# Undefined index in PHP when processing ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am making an autocomplete textbox using `AJAX` and `jQuery`. Here is my client side AJAX code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#tagtext').autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'ajax.php',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                   name_startsWith: request.term,
                   type: 'country'
                },
                 success: function( data ) {
                     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item,
                            value: item
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 0        
      }); 
});
```

And here is my server side `ajax.php` code:

```
<?php
    require_once 'db_const.php';

    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    if(isset($_GET['type']) AND $_GET['type'] == 'country'){
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT tagname FROM tagtable where tagname LIKE '".strtoupper($_GET['name_startsWith'])."%'");    
        $data = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($data, $row['tagname']);
            //echo "Hello " .$row['tagname'];
        }   
        echo json_encode($data);
    } else {
        echo "hello";
    }    
?>
```

The error is I am not getting a value as **country** in `$_GET['type']`(i.e. $_GET is not set) and it is coming outside the **if condition** and executing the **else** branch.

Can anyone will help me regarding how to get `"$_GET['type'] == country"`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that **type** is a reserved word and specifies the type of request : **GET** or **POST**. Please consider changing it with another name. See [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), an extract of the relevant part below:

> type (default: 'GET')
>
> Type: String
>
> The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET".
>
> Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

So in your example **type** will never match "country" but will be "GET"